# Dynamically setting width of after selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a simple tab like functionality using CSS.

When a tab is active, I set CSS of the selected tab using the tab-slider--tabs:after selector. However one of Tab header text is longer than the other, hence the image looks like this:

[image]

How do I dynamically set the width so that it looks like this:

[image]

```
 .tab-slider--tabs {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
.tab-slider--tabs:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  background: #345F90;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
.tab-slider--tabs.slide:after {
  left: 50%;
}
```

Here's the: [Demo Code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQrbJJ)

Update: I was able to solve this temporarily using .tab-slider--trigger{ width:30%; display: table-cell; ...}  but I am still looking for the right way to do this.

Comment: The only way I see without getting too complex is to make them the same width (large enough to fit the long string)

Comment: Can you please show how. On a mobile device, this screws up. I feel I am close but missing something essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.tab-slider--trigger {
  width:150px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #345F90;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: color 250ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but if I check this on a mobile, the text of Tab2 disapperars since the container width is smaller there. Try setting the .container {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 3rem auto;
} and see what I am saying